# Cocos2d-x error while compiling build_native.py

Tags: android, macos, cocos2d-x

whenever I try to compile cocos2d-x i get this error

```
 Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml  

...... 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build_native.py", line 43, in <module>
    build(opts.build_mode)
  File "build_native.py", line 28, in build
    raise Exception("Build dynamic library for project [ " + app_android_root + " ] fails!")
Exception: Build dynamic library for project [ /Users/Supachai/Desktop/PROJECTCPP/proj.android/../ ] fails!
```

so could you please hep me out...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you are using an old version of NDK. So you can use a new version of ndk and try again.